# Release management TFS-Triggered Deployment Timeout not allowing more than 99 minutes

Tags: tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

I am trying to execute test suite configured in MTM from Visual Studio Release Management Client using "MTM Automated Test Manager Tool".

Since the test suite will take more than 7 hours, I am trying to change the "TFS-Triggered Deployment Timeout" (Administration -> Settings -> TFS-Triggered Deployment Timeout) to 500 minutes.  But its not allowing to enter more than 99 minutes.

Is there any way to increase "TFS-Triggered Deployment Timeout".

Answer (score 1):

Modify [DeploymentStatusCheckMaxWaitInMinutes] column value in SystemSettings table in ReleaseManagement database.